# how to enable GZip compression for sqlite database download api

Tags: java, spring, sqlite, rest, gzip

We have spring rest api to download sqlite database file. Now the requirement is to compress the sqlite database file with GZip in the response. we are using wildfly 8.1 server. I tried configurations in wildfly, it's not working.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What errors do you get? Show us some code.

Comment: tried settings on wildfly mentioned in this post http://dimaki.blogspot.in/2014/12/how-to-enable-gzip-compression-in.html,  even try by setting response header ("Content-Encoding", "gzip")